# TFVC Azure DevOps Services - Check out files?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, tfvc

I've been trying to find a way to check out files and determine if files are checked out using either the .NET Client Libraries or the ADO REST API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops

There are basic samples in a Microsoft github, but none of them show anything like checking out files or determining if a file is already checked out. Is it possible to do this with one of the Changeset apis? Does this need to be done using the older .net libraries?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: TFVC is largely deprecated at this point. It's not going anywhere but it's not an area of investment for Microsoft. So I wouldn't expect the REST APIs to provide much support for manipulating TFVC content. The older .NET SOAP API libraries are going to be a better bet. I would start by looking in `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient`.

Comment: Thank you. 
I did notice the ExtendedClient listed well below the newer .net libraries on the microsoft page linked above. At that point, why would anyone try to 'upgrade' from the previous Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client and VersionControl.Client libraries?

Comment: If they're using TFVC? They very well may not want to, depending on what they're doing. Like I said, TFVC is considered legacy at this point, so if you have code that interacts with it that works there's no reason to stop using that code, because TFVC isn't getting new features anymore.